# Word 2016 is not starting, instead I saw a strange process

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

I'm trying to open my .docx guide to continue doing it. When I tried to open it, Word 2016 is not starting, instead a process named autoreactivator.exe starts. I saw in Task Manager when the file starts there are no processes related to my Microsoft Word. I double checked and the file property is set to open by Microsoft Word. I checked the autoreactivator.exe and it was in the Avast Cleanup's path and it's signed with Avast's signature.

Comment: Is that going to happen every time? Have you tried uninstall Avast to check? Perform a clean boot to avoid some software and service.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Comment: Sometimes it happens and Word is not starting, instead that process started and then ended. I checked its signature's CA and I saw it's Avast's standard signature issued by DigiCert SHA2